# Change ImageView image , Variable Error?

Tags: android, sdk

i am trying to change the image in a imageview, but when i set the variable in oncreate it gives me a yellow line making it so i cannot change my image.

in this app i am checking the Internet connection. basically, if the Internet connection is available i want to show a certain image; if not i want to show a image for that.

heres my code:

```
  @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    ImageView imagev = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    Button btnStatus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_check);

    // creating connection detector class instance
    cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

    /**
     * Check Internet status button click event
     * */
    btnStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            // get Internet status
            isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();

            // check for Internet status
            if (isInternetPresent) {
                // Internet Connection is Present
                // make HTTP requests
                showAlertDialog(AndroidDetectInternetConnectionActivity.this, "Internet Connection",
                        "You have internet connection", true);
                imagev.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.withinternet));

            } else {
                // Internet connection is not present
                // Ask user to connect to Internet
                showAlertDialog(AndroidDetectInternetConnectionActivity.this, "No Internet Connection",
                        "You don't have internet connection.", false);
                imagev.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.nointernet));
            }
        }

    });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the image view as a class variable i.e., imageV should be declared before onCreate(as a class variable) rather than inside it. It will solve your problem..

Comment: Thanks alot, i was so lost. i cant believe it was as easy as moving the code up some lines!

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the ImageView as final to use it in an inner class:

```
final ImageView imagev = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```

Btw Eclipse should display the error message

> Cannot refer to a non-final variable imagev inside an inner class
>   defined in a different method

Comment: i still get the yellow line under imagev asking me to either remove or suppress

Comment: it says "the value of the local variable imagev is not used"

Answer (score 0):

public class {activity_name} extends Activity
{
static ImageView imagev;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


//ImageView imagev = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
 //This activity name. Mainactivity if it is so.
  {activity_name}.imagev = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

Button btnStatus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_check);

// creating connection detector class instance
cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

/**
 * Check Internet status button click event
 * */
btnStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

        // get Internet status
        isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();

        // check for Internet status
        if (isInternetPresent) {
            // Internet Connection is Present
            // make HTTP requests
            showAlertDialog(AndroidDetectInternetConnectionActivity.this, "Internet Connection",
                    "You have internet connection", true);
            {activity_name}.imagev.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.withinternet));

        } else {
            // Internet connection is not present
            // Ask user to connect to Internet
            showAlertDialog(AndroidDetectInternetConnectionActivity.this, "No Internet Connection",
                    "You don't have internet connection.", false);
            {activity_name}.imagev.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.nointernet));
        }
    }

});
```

}

Comment: Declare imagev as static. I believe you cannot access it in another class.(Here OnClickListener() is a new instance of the OnClickListener).

Should work now. Just change the {activity_name} to your activity name.